# Filled rectangles instead of text while using imagettftext

Tags: php, fonts, gd, render, imagettftext

I have some problems with rendering text using imagettftext(); Somehow it just shows filled rectangles. No errors at all. http://postimage.org/image/k61c8xi0n/

- PHP Version: 5.3.8
- GD Support: Enabled
- GD Version: bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
- Freetype Support: Enabled
- Freetype linkage: With freetype
- Freetype Version: 2.4.3

Here's the code, nothing strange. Font path works.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/png");
$template = imagecreatefrompng("template.png");

imagealphablending( $template, false );
imagesavealpha( $template, true );

$white = imagecolorallocate($template, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($template, 20, 0, 100, 50, $white, 'arial.ttf', 'Some text');

imagepng($template);
?>
```

Comment: http://www.postimage.org/image/k61c8xi0n/ --> fonterror. Otherwise, try to allocate more memory: ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul Already tried, nothing changed. Still got the error. And it's Arial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code, if I set imagealphablending to true (or comment it out) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$font = dirname(__FILE__)."/arial.ttf";
imagettftext($template, 20, 0, 100, 50, $white, $font, 'Some text');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this issue by replacing TTF file with a new one. The old file got corrupted after a server migration.